# Awesome WM menu missing Firefox

Tags: firefox, menu, debian, awesome

After `sudo apt-get install awesome awesome-extra` and logging into it (with no previous configuration that I know of), there's no menu entry for Firefox. All my other stuff is there - Mutt, Meld, jEdit, BOINC, etc., only Firefox is missing. I have no `~/.config/awesome/` directory, so there should be no override in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the *menubar* instead. It's mapped to `modkey + p` in the default config, and appears to be built using .desktop files:

```
local menubar = require("menubar")
...
awful.key({ modkey }, "p", function() menubar.show() end)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default on Ubuntu, when you install Awesome, you'll get some menu items coming from the Debian menu system.  This is because the default `rc.lua` has near the top: `require("debian.menu")` and then later in `rc.lua`, under the code laying out the menu, you'll see:

```
mymainmenu = awful.menu({ items = {  [stuff snipped]
                                    { "Debian", debian.menu.Debian_menu.Debian },
                                     [stuff snipped]
                                   }
                        })
```

This means your browser(s) will be located at: "Debian" --> "Applications" --> "Network" --> "Web Browsing".  Some apps, however, may not install a Debian menu item.  Firefox, for example, seems to [no longer have one](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1999752.html).

Having said all that, I think it's preferable to just set up your own menus, because the Debian menu will have all kinds of stuff from different desktop environments you've installed.  The Debian menu system is also considered rather outdated, even by the Debian developers.  Here's a a quick read of the basics of [how to set up menus](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awful.menu) in Awesome.  If you want to see how I set up my menus, you can take a look at my `rc.lua` linked in my profile.

Comment: I have very different menu items: *Debian* → *Networking* doesn't exist; the closest is *Debian* → *Applications* → *Network*. And there's no *Web browsing* entry there - I've got *Communication*, *File Transfer* and *Monitoring*, but **none of these** contain *Firefox* (default browser), *Chromium* (also installed), *sensible-browser* or in fact, anything at all which looks like a browser shortcut. Running `sensible-browser` in a shell *does* start up Firefox, though.

Comment: I must have been distracted when I typed that... sorry!  I do have the same structure, but under "Network" I have "Web Browsing", which lists several browsers but strangely not Firefox (which I have installed).

Comment: Looks like some apps like Firefox no longer bother with a Debian menu entry:  http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1999752.html

Comment: I'm also unsure whether there was ever an item for `sensible-browser` in the original Debian menu.  In any case, the issue is how to get items onto the Debian menu; it is not an Awesome issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late on the reply here - but I found this question while having the same problem and thought I'd put my fix here for anyone else:

If you copy your `/etc/xdg/awesome`  file to `~/.config/awesome` then look in the `debian` directory, there is a `menu.lua` there.

Open the file and find

```
Debian_menu["Debian_Applications_Network"] = {
-- whatever elements are already there
}
```

and add the element

```
{ "Web Browsing", Debian_menu["Debian_Applications_Network_Web_Browsing"] },
```

to that list.

Then you can find where `Debian_menu["Debian_Applications_Network_File_Transfer"]` menu is and add another menu after it (so it's easy to find later)

```
Debian_menu["Debian_Applications_Network_Web_Browsing"] = {
{"Firefox", "/usr/bin/firefox"},
}
```

Then quit awesome and log back in and you should have Firefox in your menu.

NOTE: I put `/usr/bin/firefox` as that is where my executable for firefox is - to find where yours is type `which firefox` in the command line.